# Homepage slider not using correct images

Tags: theme-development

I am currently in the process of starting my first blog. Currently, I am stumped. I have  a homepage slider that refuses to work with me. The documentation for the theme I am currently using is located [here](http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/doc/). The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how or what the slider decides to use as an image and then the caption in the slider and how to add more to the slider. I would like it to be a the larger picture 970x360 or something like that with the caption beneath it with 3 or more pages to slide through, not have the description overlayed on it. I've gone into the theme option and messed around to no avail. I'm am lost as to where to go from here. For the visuals on the issues please see my [blog](http://konecny.dyndns.biz/blog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by hard coding. The documentation was to vague and not properly detailed for me to figure out how to use the settings.
Here is the code:

```
      <!-- BEGIN SLIDER -->
  <div id="slider">
        <a href="http://ko....cat=4"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-254" title="Android Apps" src="http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/sample1.png" alt="" width="960" height="370" /></a>
        <a href="http://ko....cat=3"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-255" title="Tutorials" src="http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/sample2.png" alt="" width="960" height="370" /></a>
        <a href="http://ko....cat=5"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-256" title="Ideas" src="http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/sample3.png" alt="" width="960" height="370" /></a>       </div>
   <div style="width:960px; margin:0 auto; background:url(http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/wp-content/themes/boldy/images/bk_shadow_slider.png) 0 0 no-repeat; height:50px;"></div>
   <!-- END SLIDER -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading at the theme documentation. You have to create new pages and insert the image for each of the slide. The pages won't be automatically added to the slider. You have to add/select pages from the theme option page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The issue is that the "Boldy" theme doesn't come with (or even tell you it has) the "Nivo Slider" and/or JQuery "Pretty Photo Light Box" dependencies.

From what I could tell, some of the code was cut-and-pasted over to the theme, but it's incomplete so it doesn't work. (I imagine they didn't catch this because they have the JQuery and Nivo slider plugins installed on whatever host they do their testing, so any missing code defaults to those.)

I picked up the "WP Ninvo Slider" plugin (http://www.nerdhead.com.br/tecnologia/wordpress/wp-nivo-slider-en) and it fixed the problem.

The theme's code (whatever's there) should override the defaults of the plugin, so any "hard coding" you might have to do (to trick out the behavior, etc.) can still be done from the theme without messing with the plugin once it's installed.